# Create GO application that Reads from SQS without terminating

Tags: go, amazon-sqs

I am new to Go and I am not an experienced dev by any means so please feel free to bash away.

I am attempting to create a GO application that will live in a container and read from AWS SQS. The goal would be the app is long living and constantly reads from the Queue.

This is the code I have so far as an example. My biggest question is if this is a bad use of GOTO and is there better way.

Thank you in advance

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sqs"
)

const (
    maxMessages = 1
)

func GetQueueURL(cfg aws.Config, queue string) (*sqs.GetQueueUrlOutput, error) {
    sqsClient := sqs.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    result, err := sqsClient.GetQueueUrl(context.TODO(), &sqs.GetQueueUrlInput{
        QueueName: &queue,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, nil
}

func GetMessages(cfg aws.Config, queueUrl string, maxMessages int32) (*sqs.ReceiveMessageOutput, error) {
    sqsClient := sqs.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    msgResult, err := sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(context.TODO(), &sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
        QueueUrl: &queueUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: maxMessages,
        WaitTimeSeconds: 10,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return msgResult, nil
}

func main() {

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
    }

    queueName := "queue"

    res, err := GetQueueURL(cfg, queueName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Got an error receiving url: %v", err)
    }
    FINDMESSAGE:
        msgRes, err := GetMessages(cfg, *res.QueueUrl, maxMessages)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Got an error while trying to retrieve messages: %v", err)
        }

        if len(msgRes.Messages) != 0 {
            fmt.Println("Message Body: " + *msgRes.Messages[0].Body)
            fmt.Println("Message Handle: " + *msgRes.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle)
        }

        fmt.Println("No Messages")

    goto FINDMESSAGE

}
```

Comment: if you don't expect a lot of messages - or even if you do - you'll get a better deal out of an SQS to Lambda integration.  In that system you're not polling SQS, but instead your function is kicked off when a message is ready.  Works really slick and is a lot less setup than fargate [see the example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-create-package.html)

Comment: Just replace the goto with a forever loop `for { ... }` and re-use the same sqs client instead of creating a new one for every set of messages that you receive.

Comment: otherwise, if you don't use SQS you pay a lot for all the requests to SQS to poll for messages, not to mention the cost of running the task 24/7 just in case you get a message.  But if you insist on writing a long running polling task, at least make sure your queue's Wait Timeout is set to the maximum.  Otherwise you'll make a huge volume of requests and costs can very quickly grow.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. A lambda makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My biggest question is if this is a bad use of GOTO and is there better way.

any use of `goto` is a bad use of `goto`, unless you can express *why* you use a goto.  Your example is a for loop:

```
for {
        msgRes, err := GetMessages(cfg, *res.QueueUrl, maxMessages)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Got an error while trying to retrieve messages: %v", err)
        }

        if len(msgRes.Messages) != 0 {
            fmt.Println("Message Body: " + *msgRes.Messages[0].Body)
            fmt.Println("Message Handle: " + *msgRes.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle)
        }

        fmt.Println("No Messages")
}
```